# Getting an error trying to invoke the predict() function to calculate model predictions using created variables

Tags: pandas, numpy

Here's my beginning code:

```
import numpy as np
```

## Create predict() function accepting a prediction probabilities list and threshold value

```
def predict(predict_prob,thresh):
    pred = []  
    for i in range(len(predict_prob)):
        if predict_prob[i] >= thresh: 
            pred.append(1) 
        else:
            pred.append(0)
    return pred
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

invoke the predict() function to calculate the model predictions using those variables. Save this output as preds and print it out.

## prediction probabilities

```
probs = [0.886,0.375,0.174,0.817,0.574,0.319,0.812,0.314,0.098,0.741,
         0.847,0.202,0.31,0.073,0.179,0.917,0.64,0.388,0.116,0.72]
```

## threshold value

```
thresh = 0.5
```

## prediction values

`preds = predict(predict_prob, thresh)` #calling predict ERROR

Here's the error:

```
NameError: name 'predict_prob' is not defined
```

But it is defined earlier when I created the function, so not sure why it's giving an error when I ran the earlier code and it didn't error on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function the wrong way. In this case, it should be:

```
preds = predict(probs, thresh)
```

You can't use 'predict_prob' outside of the function. It is defined inside and because of that it is a local variable. Also, you have 'probs' and 'thresh' perfectly prepared.

I hope that helps.